# MySQL SUM of REAL type can return inconsistent results

Tags: mysql, sql, rdbms, addition

For a column of large real values, MySQL will return 0 for their sum but if wrapped in a subselect a non-zero result will be returned. I know that usually overflow cases are undefined but it seems pretty strange to me that MySQL will return different results depending on if the query is simple or contains a subselect.

```
create table z (f_real real);
insert into z values (1.80309068027e307),(1.44090607633e308),(1.59586958712e308);
select sum(f_real) from z;
+-------------+
| sum(f_real) |
+-------------+
|           0 |
+-------------+
select * from (select sum(f_real) from z) t;
+------------------------+
| sum(f_real)            |
+------------------------+
| 1.7976931348623157e308 |
+------------------------+
```

Comment: Could be some kind of weird intermediate value problem. if you do a `select x+y+z` with your values, you get `ERROR 1690 (22003): DOUBLE value is out of range in '((1.80309068027e307 + 1.44090607633e308) + 1.59586958712e308)'` same for `select sum(...) + 0.0`

Comment: Definitely an overflow issue.  `1.7976931348623157e308` is the maximum value for a [double precision number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format), `2^1024`.

Comment: You shouldn't be using real or double in the first place if you want accurate results: http://floating-point-gui.de/  (Btw: my MySQL installation won't even let me insert  those values: "*ERROR 1264 (22003): Out of range value for column 'f_real' at row 1*")

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think this has to do with hitting a ceiling in the number that SUM can deal with.

For instance:
insert into z values (1.80309068027e307),(1.44090607633e307),(1.59586958712e307);

works fine.

insert into z values (1.80309068027e308),(1.44090607633e307),(1.59586958712e307);

doesn't work, because 1.80309068027e308 is an illegal double. I'm guessing because it's just too big.

So,it seems that if you sum up numbers that are all below the double ceiling, but the result is a double above that ceiling, it reports a 0, rather than returning an error?